# How to segue to a new view from an alertcontroller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertcontroller

I'm not sure how to do this at all. Came close but nothing is showing up on the screen. I'm looking to go from an alertcontroller to a new view when the button on the alert view is pressed. Problem is that I don't think I can have an identifier because I would need it to be connected to a button which is used to play the game. So I think my best bet is to have it programmatically segue from the alert controller to the next view without and identifier. Anyone know to do this?

```
  let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "You Finished!", message: "Congratulations for finishing the game! Now all thats left is to email us so we can contact you.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let nextAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Email", style: .Default) {
            action -> Void in
            let secondvc = EmailViewController (nibName: "EmailViewController", bundle: nil)
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondvc)
            self.presentViewController(EmailViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        alertController.addAction(nextAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.presentViewController(EmailViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

should be

```
self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I think you put the wrong controller there, because navController is useless (not used) in your original code.

Comment: I'm getting an error now for Thread 1: SIGABRT 12 top_Level_Code. any idea what that might be?

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot of what the error points to or anything?

Comment: the error is pointing to class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: Anything in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you are using nibs instead of loading your view controller from a storyboard?

You could load it from a Storyboard using the method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. (That's a scene identifier, not a segue identifier. That method gives you back a pointer to a view controller.

Loading your view controller from a nib is ok, but most people are using storyboards these days, and there are some things that you can do from storyboards that you **can't** do from nibs.

Comment: I am using storyboards but i was trying to find a way to load the next view with out having to use an identifier. I tried that and it wasn't allowing the game to be played. I didn't know about the the other one you said though, how would i include that?

Comment: You need to be clearer. I'm not sure what you mean by "...the other one you said...". You mean using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.  to load a view controller? I suggest searching on that method name in the docs.